# Asp.Net MVC Code First Column not created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am using EF4.3.1 and MVC4 code first.
My database is being created except for one column and no error is given.
Why would this column not be created? 
Should I be using the EnumDataType attribute (it doesn't seem to do anything)?

```
public class Setting
{
    public Guid SettingId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Column("DataType", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public SettingDataType DataType { get; set; }
    }


    public enum SettingDataType
    {
        [Description("String")]
        text,
        [Description("Integer")]
        integer,
        [Description("Boolean")]
        boolean
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are still not supported in EF 4.3. It does not make a difference whether you specify another DataType in the attribute.

Enums are simply completely ignored by EF when analyzing the class and generating the tables.

`Enum` support is promised for EF 5.0 though ... finally!

For now use an `int` Property instead and add another Property that casts the `int` to the `enum` value on the fly. Also just to be sure nothing breaks with the next EF version add the `Ignore` keyword.

```
public class Setting
{
    public Guid SettingId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Column("DataType", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public int DataTypeInt { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public SettingDataType DataType
    { 
        get { return (SettingDataType)this.DataTypeInt; }
        set { return this.DataTypeInt = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enums are not supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx) in EF until version 5.0.  So, you are probably just hitting this limit.